# KASLR address search space and Meltdown

Tags: security

I am reading the meltdown paper from https://meltdownattack.com. I have a question regarding the section, "Dealing with KASLR" on page 10.

It mentions that "the randomization is limited to 40 bit. Thus, if we assume a setup of the target machine with 8 GB of RAM, it is sufficient to test the address space for addresses in 8 GB steps. This allows to cover the search space of 40 bit with only 128 tests in the worst case."

Since the RAM size is 8 GB, the kernel address can be at any part of the 8 GB. I guess that's the reason it says that "it is sufficient to test the address space for addresses in 8GB steps." Is that right?

However, I cannot understand what it means that "This allows to cover the search space of 40 bit with only 128 tests in the worst case." Could someone give an example of the worst case mentioned here, and why it only requires 128 tests (tests of what...??)?

thanks,
Kai

Comment: The layout of the physical memory and the layout of the memory in the potentially 64-bit address space are two different things. Depending on the randomization strategy it might not appear as a continuous chunk and could be located here and there in pieces.

Comment: It's not necessary to tag questions with "Q:" because the only thing you can ask in a question is a question.